# Is it possible to make a video react to scrolling?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a web campaign for my BA in graphic design, and one of my ideas require a lot more knowledge about programming than what I currently have. My question is the following:

Is there some kind of code which makes a video play forward and backward depending on the scrolling? I've found multiple ways to play and pause when scrolling, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want the user to be able to scroll "through" a video, both backwards and forward.

Also, would it be hard to achieve with minimal programming knowledge? I currently understand the principles of HTML and CSS, and can edit codes without help, but I'm not very good at actually putting everything together from scratch. I do not have any experience with javascript.

I hope I'm making myself understood, this is not exactly my area of expertise.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have experience in JavaScript?

Comment: I do not, edited my post now.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible without some JavaScript knowledge.
You would have to listen to the Scroll event and according to it, you would manipulate the video to go forward and back.

Comment: You can listen on the mousewheel events, and play the video forward or backwards.
Example with button clicks: https://codepen.io/blackgghost/pen/qQmjKJ
But its not really smooth, in HTML5 there is no method to play the video reversed. BUT: You can based on the up/down scroll skip +/-5sec as example. that should work.

Answer (score 0):

How i mentioned in my comment you can set the video "currentTime" based on the mousewheel events:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
       video.currentTime += 5;
    }
    else {
       video.currentTime -= 5;
    }
});
```

```css
video{
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" controls="controls">
 <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
 <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Currently there is no method tho play the video reversed.